# How do you gitignore everything except a directory?

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to sync my desktop and laptop using a cron'd git. It works beautifully on a single directory. However I want to sync multiple config files scattered about and some other things. To do this decided to turn my home folder into a git directory and ignore everything except for a few select files and directories.

```
$ cat .gitignore
*
# test is a directory
!test
```

Does not work. Looking at another stackoverflow question, I found `*/` and used it instead of `*`. That almost worked as I wanted it to, but then all of the random single hidden files I have scattered about my home directory showed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my git ignore in my home directory.

> *

Then you have to `git add -f` stuff you want to commit. Least that is how I do it for my configs.

Comment: This would work for single config files. But for instance, I want to sync my entire documents folder. So part of the script runs `git add .` to pick up any new files that are created.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me:

```
# Ignore every directory
/*
# Except this one
!/test
```

Or

```
# Ignore every file
*
# Except these ones
!test
!test/*
!test/*/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
!test/*
```

instead. I'm not sure if this will work (wild guess), but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat .gitignore
**/*
*
# test is a directory
!test
```